# Submit button (Ajax) only works once

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms

Here's my simple HTML form & JS:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="usrtext">Enter text here:</label>
        <br />
        <textarea name="usrtext" id="usrtext" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
        <br />
        <button id="btn" type="button">Send</button>    
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = request;

        function request()
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var usrtext = document.getElementById("usrtext").value;

            xhr.open("GET", "sampleb.php?usrtext="+usrtext, true);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt)
             {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4)
                {
                    if (xhr.status == 200)
                    {
                        var temptxt = document.body.innerHTML;
                        document.body.innerHTML = temptxt + xhr.responseText;
                    }
                }
             }

            xhr.send('');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Here's the php page (sampleb.php):

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST["usrtext"]))
{
    $output = $_REQUEST["usrtext"];
}

echo $output;
?>
```

The problem I'm having is that when you enter text into the text box and submit it, the php page gets the text and sends it back fine. BUT this only works the first time. If I enter new text into the textbox and click the submit button, the ajax call does not seem to work the second time.

I'm fairly new at this, but I replaced 'request' with a console.log and if I click the button multiple times, it registers in Firebug. I also replaced 'request' with an annon function that brings up an alert box and that works on multiple button clicks... I just don't know why my 'request()' function is not being called a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the entire document body in the ajax call back. Which means the the click event you registered also is lost. You have to re-register the event again.

When you do

```
var temptxt = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = temptxt + xhr.responseText;
```

It replaces the entire document body with new DOM tree which will cause the script and and form dom to be replaced with new dom tree.

Actually what you want to do at the end of the ajax request. I'm not understanding why you have to replace the entire body of the document.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. So, just to confirm, when a new DOM tree is created without a new page load, the browser will not re-execute the HTML and JS again?

Comment: No, You effectively removing the existing html and script and replacing them with new content here. What is your actual requirement? In normal cases we will not replace the entire `document.body.innerHTML` instead we replaces only a portion of the `document`. Ex: The contents inside a particular `div` in the page